# Matplotlib: How to increase colormap/linewidth quality in streamplot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following code to generate a streamplot based on an `interp1d`-Interpolation of discrete data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

# CSV Import
a1array=pd.read_csv('a1.csv', sep=',',header=None).values
rv=a1array[:,0]
a1v=a1array[:,1]
da1vM=a1array[:,2]
a1 = interp1d(rv, a1v)
da1M = interp1d(rv, da1vM)

# Bx and By vector components
def bx(x ,y):
    rad = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
    if rad == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return x*y/rad**4*(-2*a1(rad)+rad*da1M(rad))/2.87445E-19*1E-12

def by(x ,y):
    rad = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
    if rad == 0:
        return 4.02995937E-04/2.87445E-19*1E-12
    else:
        return -1/rad**4*(2*a1(rad)*y**2+rad*da1M(rad)*x**2)/2.87445E-19*1E-12

Bx = np.vectorize(bx, otypes=[np.float])
By = np.vectorize(by, otypes=[np.float])

# Grid
num_steps = 11
Y, X = np.mgrid[-25:25:(num_steps * 1j), 0:25:(num_steps * 1j)]
Vx = Bx(X, Y)
Vy = By(X, Y)
speed = np.sqrt(Bx(X, Y)**2+By(X, Y)**2)
lw = 2*speed / speed.max()+.5

# Star Radius
circle3 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 16.3473140, color='black', fill=False)

# Plot
fig0, ax0 = plt.subplots(num=None, figsize=(11,9), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
strm = ax0.streamplot(X, Y, Vx, Vy, color=speed, linewidth=lw,density=[1,2], cmap=plt.cm.jet)
ax0.streamplot(-X, Y, -Vx, Vy, color=speed, linewidth=lw,density=[1,2], cmap=plt.cm.jet)
ax0.add_artist(circle3)
cbar=fig0.colorbar(strm.lines,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)
cbar.set_label('B[GT]', rotation=270, labelpad=8)
cbar.set_clim(0,1500)
cbar.draw_all()
ax0.set_ylim([-25,25])
ax0.set_xlim([-25,25])
ax0.set_xlabel('x [km]')
ax0.set_ylabel('z [km]')
ax0.set_aspect(1)
plt.title('polyEos(0.05,2), M/R=0.2, B_r(0,0)=1402GT', y=1.01)
plt.savefig('MR02Br1402.pdf',bbox_inches=0)
plt.show(fig0)
```

I uploaded the csv-file here if you want to try some stuff  https://www.dropbox.com/s/4t7jixpglt0mkl5/a1.csv?dl=0.
Which generates the following plot:
[image: StreamPlot]

I am actually pretty happy with the result except for one small detail, which I can not figure out: If one looks closely the linewidth and the color change in rather big steps, which is especially visible at the center:

[image: Problem]

Is there some way/option with which I can decrease the size of this steps to especially make the colormap smother?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your script with neither py 2.7.6 and 3.4.3, it throws at line 36 `TypeError: unorderable types: numpy.ndarray() < str()`. I'm trying to find where is the wrong cast but I was not lucky. Any hint on your python version/setup?

Comment: The code above works for me in Python 3.5.2 and in Python 2.7.12 on Linux and with Python 3.5.2 on Windows. I do not know about that errow code. Just looking at the error I would assume it happens at the csv-import, maybe something is off with your `pandas` or `numpy` packages.

Comment: I updated to python 3.5 and now it works

Comment: There is no setting to adjust this unfortunately. The step size is determined by an adaptive integration routine inside `matplotlib/streamplot.py`. You could try adjusting the [`maxerror` and `maxds`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v2.0.0b2/lib/matplotlib/streamplot.py#L462:L473) values, but I didn't succeed in getting a nice looking plot that way. Probably a better idea is to manually interpolate the `LineCollection` that you get back from `pyplot.streamplot`.

Comment: Thank you @user6758673 I did not get good results tweaking `maxerror` and `maxds` either. With `strm.lines.getpath()` I was able to get the `path` object of my streamplot but working with that object to get smother curves seems to be not that easy. Maybe someone knows a way to do that or a way to get `streamplot`'s integrator working with smaller step?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had another look at this and it wasnt as painful as I thought it might be.

Add:

```
    subdiv = 15
    points = np.arange(len(t[0]))
    interp_points = np.linspace(0, len(t[0]), subdiv * len(t[0]))
    tgx = np.interp(interp_points, points, tgx)
    tgy = np.interp(interp_points, points, tgy)
    tx = np.interp(interp_points, points, tx)
    ty = np.interp(interp_points, points, ty)
```

after `ty` is initialised in the trajectories loop (line `164` in my version). Just substitute whatever number of subdivisions you want for `subdiv = 15`. All the segments in the streamplot will be subdivided into as many equally sized segments as you choose. The colors and linewidths for each will still be properly obtained from interpolating the data.

Its not as neat as changing the integration step but it does plot exactly the same trajectories.

[image: subdiv = 15]

Comment: Thank you very much Toby: That is exactly what I was looking for! I think this subdivision option is a great addition to `streamplot`.

Comment: I agree, would be good to propose an improvement to `matplotlib`. I also find the default segment size too large for high quality figures.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind changing the `streamplot` code (`matplotlib/streamplot.py`), you could simply decrease the size of the integration steps. Inside `_integrate_rk12()` the maximum step size is defined as:

```
maxds = min(1. / dmap.mask.nx, 1. / dmap.mask.ny, 0.1)
```

If you decrease that, lets say:

```
maxds = 0.1 * min(1. / dmap.mask.nx, 1. / dmap.mask.ny, 0.1)
```

I get this result (left = new, right = original):

[image]

Of course, this makes the code about 10x slower, and I haven't thoroughly tested it, but it seems to work (as a quick hack) for this example.

About the density (mentioned in the comments): I personally don't see the problem of that. It's not like we are trying to visualize the actual path line of (e.g.) a particle; the density is already some arbitrary (controllable) choice, and yes it is influenced by choices in the integration, but I don't thing that it changes the (not quite sure how to call this) required visualization we're after.

The results (density) do seem to converge a bit for decreasing step sizes, this shows the results for decreasing the integration step with a factor {1,5,10,20}:

[image]

Comment: Oeps, should have read the comments first.. But anyhow, for me changing `maxds` does give me good results. @ M. J. Steil, how did you try to change `maxds`?

Comment: This works on the line increments but somehow it also affects the density quite severely: The lines at the center get disconnectet and look off. But for the increments on the separte lines your solution works. Somehow all this parameters are connected and tweaking them effects the entire plot. I am pretty happy with the lines in the original post but increasing the increments on them gives different lines.

Comment: The integration is stopped when reaching a grid point where another streamline has already passed; I'd have to look closer at the code, but I guess that with smaller steps, the individual segments of a single streamline flag more grid points as already being visited, influencing the (visual) density.

Comment: At least, that's what I remember from very early versions of `streamplot`, but things seem to have changed a bit...

Comment: Yes that is probably still how it works. Without changing the code massively one can not just increase segments on a line without affecting the entire plot.

Comment: To your EDIT: Yes you are right the  density arbitrary and those plots do not display particle flow. Still that being said I personaly dislike ths gabs apearing left and right to the center but thats the way it gets when one turns up `maxds`. I will play a bit with the given settings and find a compromise. Thank you for your answer: it is the best one can do without making massive changes to the code. If some one does not come out with a neat mod of the code in the next few days I will accept this answer and give you the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

You could increase the `density` parameter to get more smooth color transitions,
but then use the `start_points` parameter to reduce your overall clutter.
The start_points parameter allows you to explicity choose the location and
number of trajectories to draw.  It overrides the default, which is to plot
as many as possible to fill up the entire plot.

But first you need one little fix to your existing code:
According to the [streamplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot) documentation, the X and Y args should be 1d arrays, not 2d arrays as produced by mgrid.
It looks like passing in 2d arrays is supported, but it is undocumented
and it is currently not compatible with the start_points parameter.

Here is how I revised your X, Y, Vx, Vy and speed:

```
# Grid
num_steps = 11
Y = np.linspace(-25, 25, num_steps)
X = np.linspace(0, 25, num_steps)
Ygrid, Xgrid = np.mgrid[-25:25:(num_steps * 1j), 0:25:(num_steps * 1j)]
Vx = Bx(Xgrid, Ygrid)
Vy = By(Xgrid, Ygrid)
speed = np.hypot(Vx, Vy)
lw = 3*speed / speed.max()+.5
```

Now you can explicitly set your `start_points` parameter.  The start points are actually
"seed" points.  Any given stream trajectory will grow in *both* directions
from the seed point.  So if you put a seed point right in the center of
the example plot, it will grow both up and down to produce a vertical
stream line.

Besides controlling the *number* of trajectories, using the
`start_points` parameter also controls the *order* they are
drawn.  This is important when considering how trajectories terminate.
They will either hit the border of the plot, or they will terminate if
they hit a cell of the plot that already has a trajectory.  That means
your first seeds will tend to grow longer and your later seeds will tend
to get limited by previous ones.  Some of the later seeds may not grow
at all.  The default seeding strategy is to plant a seed at every cell,
which is pretty obnoxious if you have a high density.  It also orders
them by planting seeds first along the plot borders and spiraling inward.
This may not be ideal for your particular case.  I found a very simple
strategy for your example was to just plant a few seeds between those
two points of zero velocity, y=0 and x from -10 to 10. Those trajectories
grow to their fullest and fill in most of the plot without clutter.

Here is how I create the seed points and set the density:

```
num_streams = 8
stptsy = np.zeros((num_streams,), np.float)
stptsx_left = np.linspace(0, -10.0, num_streams)
stptsx_right = np.linspace(0, 10.0, num_streams)
stpts_left = np.column_stack((stptsx_left, stptsy))
stpts_right = np.column_stack((stptsx_right, stptsy))
density = (3,6)
```

And here is how I modify the calls to `streamplot`:

```
strm = ax0.streamplot(X, Y, Vx, Vy, color=speed, linewidth=lw, density=density,
                  cmap=plt.cm.jet, start_points=stpts_right)
ax0.streamplot(-X, Y, -Vx, Vy, color=speed, linewidth=lw,density=density,
                  cmap=plt.cm.jet, start_points=stpts_left)
```

The result basically looks like the original, but with smoother color transitions and only 15 stream lines.  (sorry no reputation to inline the image)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Explicitly setting the `start_points` is certainly a good idea if one has a specific look in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use a colormap other than jet. Perhaps `cmap=plt.cmap.plasma`.

[image: The same graph with the plasma colormap]

Wierd looking graphs obscure understanding of the data.

For data which is ordered in some way, like by the speed vector magnitude in this case, uniform sequential colormaps will always look smoother. The brightness of sequential maps varies monotonically over the color range, removing large percieved color changes over small ranges of data. The uniform maps vary linearly over their whole range which makes the main features in the data much more visually apparent.

[image: Perceptually Uniform Sequential Color Maps]
<sub>(source: [matplotlib.org](http://matplotlib.org/_images/lightness_00.png))</sub>

The jet colormap spans a very wide variety of brightnesses over its range with in inflexion in the middle. This is responsible for the particularly egregious red to blue transition around the center region of your graph.

[image: Jet and other Non-Sequential Color Maps]
<sub>(source: [matplotlib.org](http://matplotlib.org/_images/lightness_05.png))</sub>

[The matplotlib user guide on choosing a color map](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html) has a few recomendations for about selecting an appropriate map for a given data set.

I dont think there is much else you can do to improve this by just changing parameters in your plot.

The streamplot divides the graph into cells with `30*density[x,y]` in each direction, at most one streamline goes through each cell. The only setting which directly increases the number of segments is the density of the grid matplotlib uses. Increasing the Y density will decrease the segment length so that the middle region may transition more smoothly. The cost of this is an inevitable cluttering of the graph in regions where the streamlines are horizontal.

You could also try to normalise the speeds differently so the the change is artifically lowered in near the center. At the end of the day though it seems like it defeats the point of the graph. The graph should provide a useful view of the data for a human to understand. Using a colormap with strange inflexions or warping the data so that it looks nicer removes some understanding which could otherwise be obtained from looking at the graph.

A more detailed discussion about the issues with colormaps like jet can be found on this [blog](https://mycarta.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/the-rainbow-is-dead-long-live-the-rainbow-part-1/).

Comment: Changing the colormap to a uniform map like `cmap=plt.cmap.plasma` makes the effect less visible but one can still see that at the center the steps in which the color changes are still pretty big. Yes maybe those maps are better suited for this kinds of plot but I still would like to figure out a way to divide the lines in smaler segments. The density does not affect this at all: if I increase or decrease density I get more or less stream lines but they are still rendered the same way.

Comment: @M. J. Steil It certainly looks to me like doubling the Y density halves the segment length near the center where the segments are y aligned. [Left half y density of 2,right half y density of 4](http://imgur.com/a/pnyl3)

Comment: Looking at it closely: you are right. It seems like the colormap realy is coupled to density: the problem (and the reason why I did not see it at first) is with higher density only a few streamlines are actually plotted at the center. Maybe it realy is impossible to increase the increments on the streams seperatly from the density.

Comment: @M. J. Steil I think it may well be impossible by changing any of the parameters as is. Looking at the way streamplot is implemented its probably possible to add a line subdivision parameter without too much pain. I'll give it a go later and if it works I'll post it as a new anwser.

Comment: Scratch that, lots of pain.